# Unity | Как повесить на куб собственную текстуру на все стороны?

Tags: c#, unity3d, блок

Как наложить верхнюю, нижнюю и боковые текстуры для блока?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Импортируй куб из 3д редактора с готовой UV-разверткой

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u9njGqTGKWQ

И это одна текстура а не 3